# Rebuild Reporting Database procedure fails with "Aggregation task not found" error

Tags: reporting, aggregation

We're attempting to rebuild our reporting database in order process historical data from Mongo. This has failed on us several times. This time we were able to catch the error message: `ERROR Failed Rebuild - history processing. AggregationType: Automation. Error: Aggregation task was not found.`

It comes right after a couple of failed SQL calls, `invalid object` errors for the `FormFieldValues` and `Fact_FormEvents` tables. We've confirmed that these tables don't exist in our database. I'm not entirely convinced fixing that will fix our aggregation issues though, as those errors occur numerous times during the process without it bombing out (we're still going to fix that issue, though, obviously).

Anyone have any experience with this?

Our installation is 8.1u3 with the WFFM module.

*edit: adding more error details*

We don't have a stack trace, per se, but here's the context at least:

```
12176 09:57:19 ERROR Exception when storing an aggregation result into reporting database. Item will be postponed and retried later.
Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
Message: Invalid object name 'Fact_FormEvents'.
Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.SqlReportingStorageProvider.Commit(SqlDataApi api, IReportingStorageItemBatch batch, Func`2 filter)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.SqlReportingStorageProvider.<>c__DisplayClass6.<StoreBatch>b__1()
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.NullRetryer.ExecuteNoResult(Action action, Action recover)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.SqlReportingStorageProvider.Store(IReportingStorageItemBatch batch)
12408 09:57:21 ERROR Failed Rebuild - history processing. AggregationType: Automation. Error: Aggregation task was not found.
```

Note that the stack trace there is for a separate but possibly related error (the failed SQL calls I mentioned previously). The aggregation error itself doesn't provide any more detail than that.

*edit 2: aggregation processors from the showconfig.aspx*

```
<interactions>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.Pipeline.TrafficProcessor, Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation" />
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.Pipeline.ValueBySourceProcessor, Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation" />
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.Pipeline.PageViewsProcessor, Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation" />
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.Pipeline.ValueByBusinessUnitProcessor, Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation" />
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.Pipeline.VisitsProcessor, Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation" />
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.Pipeline.FailuresProcessor, Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation" />
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.Pipeline.ConversionsProcessor, Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation" />
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.Pipeline.DownloadsProcessor, Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation" />
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.Pipeline.SiteSearchesProcessor, Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation" />
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.Pipeline.FollowHitsProcessor, Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation" />
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.Pipeline.SlowPagesProcessor, Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation" />
    <!-- Aggregators for indexing experience data -->
    <processor type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.Aggregators.AnalyticsVisitAggregator, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics" patch:source="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.config">
        <param desc="name">VisitAggregationObservable</param>
    </processor>
    <processor type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.Aggregators.AnalyticsVisitPageAggregator, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics" patch:source="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.config">
        <param desc="name">VisitPageAggregationObservable</param>
    </processor>
    <processor type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.Aggregators.AnalyticsVisitPageEventAggregator, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics" patch:source="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.config">
        <param desc="name">VisitPageEventAggregationObservable</param>
    </processor>
    <processor type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.Aggregators.AnalyticsContactAggregator, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics" patch:source="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.config">
        <param desc="name">ContactAggregationObservable</param>
    </processor>
    <processor type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.Aggregators.AnalyticsContactTagAggregator, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics" patch:source="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.config">
        <param desc="name">ContactTagAggregationObservable</param>
    </processor>
    <processor type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.Aggregators.AnalyticsAddressAggregator, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics" patch:source="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.config">
        <param desc="name">AddressAggregationObservable</param>
    </processor>
    <processor type="Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Pipelines.Interactions.TreeProcessor, Sitecore.PathAnalyzer" patch:source="Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Processing.config">
        <LivePool ref="aggregationProcessing/processingPools/pathAnalyzerLive" />
        <HistoryPool ref="aggregationProcessing/processingPools/pathAnalyzerHistory" />
    </processor>
    <processor type="Sitecore.WFFM.Analytics.Aggregation.Processors.FormSummary.FormSummaryProcessor, Sitecore.WFFM.Analytics" patch:source="Sitecore.WFFM.Analytics.config" />
    <processor type="Sitecore.WFFM.Analytics.Aggregation.Processors.FormEvents.FormEventsProcessor, Sitecore.WFFM.Analytics" patch:source="Sitecore.WFFM.Analytics.config" />
    <processor type="Sitecore.WFFM.Analytics.Aggregation.Processors.FormStatisticsByContact.FormStatisticsByContactProcessor, Sitecore.WFFM.Analytics" patch:source="Sitecore.WFFM.Analytics.config" />
    <processor type="Sitecore.ContentTesting.Analytics.Aggregation.Pipeline.MvTestingProcessor, Sitecore.ContentTesting" patch:source="Sitecore.ContentTesting.Processing.Aggregation.config" />
    <processor type="Sitecore.ContentTesting.Analytics.Aggregation.Pipeline.MvTestingDetailsProcessor, Sitecore.ContentTesting" patch:source="Sitecore.ContentTesting.Processing.Aggregation.config" />
    <processor type="Sitecore.ContentTesting.Analytics.Aggregation.Pipeline.TestPageClicksProcessor, Sitecore.ContentTesting" patch:source="Sitecore.ContentTesting.Processing.Aggregation.config" />
    <processor type="Sitecore.ContentTesting.Analytics.Aggregation.Pipeline.TestConversionsProcessor, Sitecore.ContentTesting" patch:source="Sitecore.ContentTesting.Processing.Aggregation.config" />
    <processor type="Sitecore.ContentTesting.Analytics.Aggregation.Pipeline.PageViewsByLanguageProcessor, Sitecore.ContentTesting" patch:source="Sitecore.ContentTesting.Processing.Aggregation.config">
        <DateTimePrecision type="Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.Data.DateTimeDayPrecisionStrategy, Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation" />
    </processor>
    <processor type="Sitecore.ContentTesting.Analytics.Aggregation.Pipeline.PersonalizationProcessor, Sitecore.ContentTesting" patch:source="Sitecore.ContentTesting.Processing.Aggregation.config" />
    <processor type="Sitecore.ContentTesting.Analytics.Aggregation.Pipeline.PersonalizationRulesExposure, Sitecore.ContentTesting" patch:source="Sitecore.ContentTesting.Processing.Aggregation.config" />
    <!-- The pipeline processor is building Facts and Dimensions for each segment registered in Experience Analytics -->
    <processor type="Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Aggregation.Pipeline.SegmentProcessor, Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics" patch:source="Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Aggregation.config" />
</interactions>
```

Comment: check this article https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/977445 Good luck,
Naim

Comment: You need to have those aggregation pipelines to be fixed. The reason is because this is executed sequentially. So, if one gets an error, the other aggregations will not be executed

Comment: If you have a complete stack trace, please edit your post to include that.

Comment: We don't have a stack trace on the aggregation error, but I've added a bit of context.

Comment: Can you share the different aggregation processors that you have. It is at the following xpath: `pipelines -> group groupName="analytics.aggregation" -> pipelines -> interactions`

Comment: Sure. Added to the main question, as it was too large to put in a comment.

Comment: Your issue is with the Sitecore.WFFM.Analytics.Aggregation.Processors.FormEvents. Try to comment it and see if the error goes away. Note that you need to see the version of the release note of the module WFFM you are using because if the table is no more present that mentioned pipeline should not be present or you may have miss the creation of the table formevents. I have not used WFFM on sitecore XP but please see into the notes. As a workaround, comment out the WFFM aggregation pipelines

Comment: If that's the case, is it likely that adding those tables would also resolve the issue?

Answer (score 3):

**Brief Problem Description**

When data have been captured in the MongoDB, on session end, data will be aggregated to the reporting database through Aggregation Pipelines.

**Issue**

Your issue is with the following pipelines:

```
<processor type="Sitecore.WFFM.Analytics.Aggregation.Processors.FormSummary.FormSummaryProcessor, Sitecore.WFFM.Analytics" patch:source="Sitecore.WFFM.Analytics.config" />
<processor type="Sitecore.WFFM.Analytics.Aggregation.Processors.FormEvents.FormEventsProcessor, Sitecore.WFFM.Analytics" patch:source="Sitecore.WFFM.Analytics.config" />
<processor type="Sitecore.WFFM.Analytics.Aggregation.Processors.FormStatisticsByContact.FormStatisticsByContactProcessor, Sitecore.WFFM.Analytics" patch:source="Sitecore.WFFM.Analytics.config" />
```

As you already specified in the question that you don't have the tables

- Fact_FormEvents
- FormFieldValues

This is because you did not execute the `SQL` script to create them.

**Solution**

Navigate to the `[site root]\Website\Data\` and execute the `WFFM_Analytics.sql` on the reporting database. This will create the required tables.

Comment: We did this yesterday and kicked off another rebuild. Last one took ten days to fail, so it'll be awhile before I have a response. Hoping this turns out to be the cause. Thanks! I'll mark this as the answer once I can confirm that it works.

Comment: Failed again. We're still getting errors about one of the tables (Fact_FormSummary), but it exists and contains data and the errors continue after the process failed, so I don't think they're related.

Comment: Try to clear the data from the fact_formsummary or remove the pipeline

Answer (score 0):

Michael- can you please go through this document and check the basic configurations are in place? sometimes a small configuration issue can create big problems. 
https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/81/setting_up_and_maintaining/xdb/server_considerations/walkthrough_rebuilding_the_reporting_database

Comment: That's the exact document we've been following for this procedure.